# Analyzer to find , e.g: "starbucks" when mistakenly querying "star bucks"

Tags: elasticsearch

How would I define an analyzer so a query recalls a document with term "starbucks" when mistakenly querying "star bucks"?

Or in general: how would I define an analyzer that is able to search for combined terms by omitting term-separators/ spaces, in the supplied query?

N-grams clearly don't work, since you'd have to know to split up the term 'starbucks' on indexing in 2 separate terms 'star' and 'bucks'. Splitting on syllables might be enough, but not sure if that's possible (or scales)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fuzzy Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html).

Here is a full working sample:

```
PUT test1

POST test1/a
{
  "item1": "starbucks"
}

POST test1/a
{
  "item1": "foo"
}

GET test1/a/_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "item1": "star bucks"
    }
  }
}
```